# How do I append an element to another element?

Tags: jquery

How can I use jQuery to append `p.test` to `h3` if `p` is outside of `h3` like below? So basically I want to pick it from where it is and put it in h3.

```
<h3>
     <a href="/">Test</a>
</h3>
<p class="test">Test Test Test</p>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, at least not reliably. Heading elements are [defined as only being able to contain inline elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/global.html#h-7.5.5). Paragraphs are not permitted inside headings.

```
<!ELEMENT (%heading;)  - - (%inline;)* -- heading -->
```

If it was permitted then the syntax would be:

```
$('h3').append($('p.test'));
```

Comment: thanks @david. just out of curiosity, does it also work without the second $ and brackets around `p.test`?